# scalafmt changes line endings, how configure it to ignore them?

Tags: scala, sbt, line-endings, scalafmt

After running any SBT task (e.g. `compile`) scalafmt is executed and changes line endings on some computers (most of them use Windows). Is it possible to set line endings in scalafmt.conf or any other way?

Thanks.

Comment: Currently I'm going to verify lineEndings=preserve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

adding to scalafmt.conf

```
lineEndings=preserve
```

solves the problem

Comment: additionaly, ```docstrings.style = keep``` helps keeping the line breaks in documentary comments also.